# BCEWithLogitsLoss Multi-label Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, multilabel-classification

I'm a bit confused about how to accumulate the batch losses to obtain the epoch loss.

Two questions:

1. Is `#1` (see comments below) correct way to calculate loss with masks)
2. Is `#2` correct way to report epoch loss)

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters, lr=1e-3, weight_decay=1e-5)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_weight)

for epoch in range(10):
    EPOCH_LOSS = 0.
    
    for inputs, gt_labels, masks in training_dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        
        #1: Is this the correct way to calculate batch loss? Do I multiply batch_loss with outputs.shape[0[ before adding it to epoch_loss?
        batch_loss = (masks * criterion(outputs, gt_labels.float())).mean()
        EPOCH_LOSS += batch_loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    #2: then what do I do here? Do I divide the EPOCH_LOSS with len(training_dataloader)?
    print(f'EPOCH LOSS: {EPOCH_LOSS/len(training_dataloader)}:.3f')
```

Answer (score 2):

In your criterion, you have got the default `reduction` field set (see [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html)), so your masking approach won't work. You should use your masking one step earlier (prior to the loss calculation) like so:

```
batch_loss = (criterion(outputs*masks, gt_labels.float()*masks)).mean()
```

OR

```
batch_loss = (criterion(outputs[masks], gt_labels.float()[masks])).mean()
```

But, without seeing your data it might be a different format. You might want to check that this is working as expected.

In regards to your actual question, it depends on how you want to represent your data. What I would do is just to sum all of the batches' losses and represent that, but you can choose to divide by the number of batches if you want to represent the AVERAGE loss of each batch in the epoch.

Because this is purely an illustrative property of your model, it actually doesn't matter which one you pick, as long as it's consistent between epochs to represent the fact that your model is learning.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I'll try your approach with masks and let you know if it works.

So if I were to sum loss of all the batches, do I need to do `epoch_loss += outputs.size(0) * batch_loss` followed by `epoch_loss/len(dataloader)`?

Comment: No, because all i think you're trying to do is track your loss over the epoch. So all you have to do is make it consistent, it should be enough to do `epoch_loss += batch_loss`. You can divide it at the end by the length of the dataloader if you want to do the average batch loss.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. However, when I do this, the loss is quite high. Can you let me know if the following makes sense (I added your way of using mask):
`batch_loss = (criterion(outputs*masks, gt_labels.float()*masks)).sum() / masks.sum() `. I feel like I need to normalize it using the mask. Or should I stick with the former approach?

Comment: There is already a mean in your criterion so you don't need to divide it. See the defaults in the documentation.